# Updating data from a table/grid

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 11 application and an .NET Core web API version 3.1 for the backend. I have a table/grid that has 2 checkboxes and a textbox. I would like the user to be able to make changes in the table/grid and then click a save button to save the changes made from the table. Is there an "Angular" best practice way of doing this or do I have to loop through the grid data and send each row up to be updated? How would I grab the row when looping? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of drivers | paginate: { itemsPerPage: pagination?.itemsPerPage, currentPage: pagination?.currentPage, totalItems: pagination?.totalItems} ; let i = index">
          <td width="65px">
          </td>
          <td width="90px">
            <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked={{user.reviewed}} /></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div *ngIf="user.allowDelete" class="center"><input type="checkbox" checked={{user.allowDelete}} /></div>
          </td>
          
          <td class='clickable-row'>
            {{user.ein}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{user.lastName}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{user.firstName}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea">{{ user.comments }}</textarea>
          </td>
         
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: Hi @Dennis, what do you mean by "send each row up to be updated"? do you want to communicate with the backend the informations about the row to the save event?

Comment: Yes. If there are 10 rows in the grid and they edit 1 or all 10 rows and the user clicks a save button I need to send the updates to an API using HTTP rest call.